# How to label rows in a UITableView as 1, 2, 3 etc

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a *UITableView* with a *CustomCell* which contains multiple labels. In one of these labels I want to show the row number as 1, 2, 3 etc. I know I could probably do this with a variable and increase it every time a new item is entered to the table but I would like to use the `indexPath.row` from the tableView to make my code cleaner.

Here is what I have that kind of works, I say `kind of` because it always adds a 1 to the first two rows, so in theory is not working.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reusableCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    // some other labels here

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let rowCounter = indexPath.row + 1
        cell.displayRowNumber!.text = String(rowCounter)
    }else{
        cell.displayRowNumber!.text = String(indexPath.row)
        print(indexPath.row)
    }

    return cell
}
```

Any suggestion?

FYI - The user can also delete rows by swiping.

Thanks

Comment: If want them numbered sequentially from 1, it should simply be indexPath.row + 1, unconditionally.

Comment: It works, the only thing I dont like about it is that I had to `reloadData()` in the `commitEditingStyle` because it was not updating when a row was deleted by swiping and what I don't like is the fact that it does not animate when the row is deleted. Not a big deal I guess.

Comment: @fs_tigre, to delete the cell without call `reloadData()` and with animation, you have to use `tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation:. Left)`, where the `indexPath` is the row/section of the deleted cell.

Comment: It is deleting fine and animating but it does not update to 1,2,3... when a row is deleted and of I reload it updates but I lose the animation.

Comment: You don't need to call `reloadData` when you delete a row. But at a minimum you need to reload all of the visible rows below the row that was deleted. Same if you insert a row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make your logic works, all you have to do is add 1 to the `indexPath.row`. The row number is gonna grow from 0 to `n` items. And, by adding 1 to all iterations, you will obtain the result of item counter (1, 2, 3, 4, ... , n).

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reusableCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    // some other labels here
    let rowCounter = indexPath.row + 1
    cell.displayRowNumber!.text = String(rowCounter)

    return cell
}
```

Comment: As I previously commented, It works but I don't like the fact that I had to `reloadData()` in the `commitEditingStyle` method because it was not updating when a row was deleted by swiping and what I don't like is the fact that it does not animate when the row is deleted. Not a big deal I guess.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, simply set your displayRowNumber.text to `String(indexPath.row + 1)`.

When you add or delete a row, the numbers won't be right any more. Calling reloadData() will fix the row numbers, but you won't get the row animation.

If you want to both update your row numbers AND have the delete animation work correctly, you could trigger the delete animation, then use the table view's `indexPathsForVisibleRows` property to get an array of the visible cells, and loop through that array, fetch each cell using the table view method `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, and update the labels of those cells yourself. The effect would be that the delete animation would happen, then the numbers would update without the rest of the cells redrawing.

Comment: Do you mind showing a quick example of what you described? I cannot make it work.

Comment: I don't have any existing code. I'd have to create a test project just to do this, and don't really have time for that. Edit your post and add your new code at the end and I'll take a look.

Comment: I understand, I will try figure it out myself, I'm just a little confused as to where the update needs to happen, in the `commitEditingStyle ` method or in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Thanks a lot for your help.